# Hidden folder and files

Tags: 14.04

I have two folder. One folder is hidden and another is not.

But both have the same name . `.fold` and `fold`.

How do I enter into `.fold` and change the properties of it.

Here `.fold` is hidden that I saw from terminal using `ls -al`

Comment: Simply do `cd .fold` and your there

Comment: The name is not the same... one is called ".fold" and the other just "fold" the dot is not some kind of magic thing showing you that it is invisible it's actually another name. It's just that almost all recent shells and file explorers interpret the dot at the beginning as a "hidden" file. Also linux is case sensetive, that means you can also have the folder ".Fold" or ".fOld" and they are all different folders.

Comment: Hi, 
Your question is not clear do you want to show your hiden folder or do you want to explore.

Comment: I think he wants to change the permissions of .fold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply do:

```
cd .fold
```

And to change the properties:

```
chmod -R 777 .fold
chown -R user:group .fold
```

**Note when in the folder ( after doing `cd .fold`) you use the command like so** to change the properties of the contents of `.fold`:

```
chmod -R 777 ./*
chown -R user:group ./*
```

And to affect the `.fold` (parent folder, rather than its content) alone use:

```
chmod 777 .
chown user:group .
```